# Spring password encoder

Tags: spring, password-encryption

I would like to use new interface:

```
org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
```

instead of deprecated:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;
```

But ShaPasswordEncoder which is not deprecated does not satisfy as an autowire bean (i.e. does not support methods of this new interface)

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;
```

Is there any alternative or new class? It seems there are three implementations and SHA is only 256 not 512 as provided by ShaPasswordEncoder

Or I just simply inject the class directly?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with BCryptPasswordEncoder, see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html