# How can bcrypt be save?

Tags: spring-security, bcrypt, sha

Because Spring deprecated the old interface

```
org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
```

I looked for alternatives that work with

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;
```

My search points me to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678325

I tested bcrypt and I was interested how it works.

The explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165 points me to one question.

If `$2a$10$ZaDBCZaI59IMdKuBiRdubuMa2h/itIYIwqLHpS1q245ISD90xsjkW` contains all information about the type of encoding and the salt and so on, and this is stored in my database why is it save?
If someone has this "hash" he can easily decrypt it with brute force.

Within my previous project I used a SHA encode with a system wide secret salt. In this scenario the hash stole from the database can't easily be decrypted.

So why is bcrypt preferred to a SHA with system wide salt?

Answer (score 0):

2 points:

1. Bcrypt is designed to resist brute force attacks by having a configurable complexity that makes the process arbitrarily slow. Refer to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for more details
2. Using the same hash for all passwords, as your existing system does, may be vulnerable to differential attacks, since each password in the database is known to contain a shared component.